# Reading local email in Thunderbird without postfix

Tags: debian, email, postfix, thunderbird

Is this possible? And if so how?

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE on my personal computer (which I also don't configure remotely). When opening the /var/mail/username file KMail tells me "The file contains multiple messages. Only the first message is shown." and just displays a single email. I can open the file with a text-editor to see all the emails in plaintext. This makes me believe that postfix isn't really necessary to view these emails and get notified for new ones which is all that I want to do.

Comment: Postfix is used for receiving and sending mail, if you only want to read mail postfix is not needed.

Comment: @Henrik Okay, but then how can I read them in Thunderbird without installing it? The only answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-do-i-read-local-email-in-thunderbird) that does not require postfix does not work for me. (And I also found it strange that Debian+KDE does not come bundled with software/functionality required for this to work.)